# RSS feed does not load to the WebView correctly

Tags: xcode, rss

I created an RSS reader through Xcode and seem to have problems when I load a CRAIGSLIST RSS feed into the NSURL.. It seems to work with the below code.. But when I put a Craigslist RSS in there it does not brings me to a 404 error in craigslist. Any thoughts?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
feeds = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://images.apple.com/main/rss/hotnews/hotnews.rss"];
parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
[parser setDelegate:self];
[parser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:NO];
[parser parse];
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you use 'http://chicago.craigslist.org/search/ata?format=rss'? or 'http://chicago.craigslist.org/search/ata?format=rss&amp;format=rss' ? You have to probably use the second one, because it specifies the category.